# Magento default search with categoy

Tags: category, catalogsearch, search, advanced-search, category-products

For the default quicksearch, am adding a dropdown before quicksearch with values as all the categories available(like all products, living room, bedroom, cellphones, accessories, digital cameras and rest).

Now whenever user selects one dropdown value and searches for a item, then if the item belongs to the selected dropdown value then it should result values.otherwise it should say "NO items found for this category"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Try this extension](http://www.geekyplugins.com/magento/catalog-category-search.dot). I don't think it's 100% what you need, but it's almost...
It add a category selection near the quick search and if you select a category it will only search in that category.
The only thing you need to fix yourself is the message for no products found.
I've used the extension in the past and it worked nicely.